# Lightbox - Janela sem botão fechar

Tags: jquery

baixei o pacote do LightBox em http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/, iniciei o script e o css :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.css" />
```

Editei o CSS para o local onde está as imagens (Close.png e o Loading.png) no diretorio Images do meu projeto e no meu código abaixo, para listar as imagens em miniatura. Por fim, ao  clicar nas imagens em miniatura,  abrir a imagem original:

```
echo "<br><br><br><a href='diretorio/".$row['foto']." '><img  src='teste.php?img=diretorio/".$row['foto']."' width='100' height='100' border='0'  <br/> <br/><br/></a>";
```

Abre a miniatura sem problema, e ao clicar na imagem, direciona para a imagem original. So que não está aparecendo o botão fechar, ou seja, não é possível fechar a tela modal da imagem. O que estou errando?

Comment: Tem que ver se copiou as pastas corretamente esse plugin tem uma pasta de images! é isso.

Comment: Eu copiei as duas imagens que precisava e guardei em um diretório de imagens do projeto e setei no CSS o caminho destas imagens.

Comment: Tem 6 lugares se mudou nos 6?

Comment: Sim, acabei de confirmar. Para não ter erro de caminho, coloquei as imagens dentro do mesmo diretorio CSS. So o botao de close que não aparece.O arquivo que eu estou alterando é o lightbox.css

Comment: tem a imagem de algum exemploai ? já debugou no navegador

Comment: Você quer a imagem (miniatura)? caso seja, está em meu projeto local, não está disponível via web.

Comment: Não você disse que o botão não está aparecendo onde deveria aparecer, é dificil sem ver alguma coisa, como você sabe que não aparece (pergunta até idiota) tente postar um print screen disso.

Comment: descobri o erro e foi uma falta de atenção minha. Um os arquivos jquery, quando carreguei ele no inicio da pagina, esqueci de por o .js no final. Ja está Ok. agradeço por sua ajuda.